# How to prevent duplicate items from being added to an IRepository?

Tags: c#, mvvm, collections, duplicates, irepository

I've used an `IRepository` to store a `subject` and `score` pair in a repository. Now I'm trying to figure out how to prevent duplicate subject names, from being added to that repository.

I tried the following solution using a statement to check if the repositry already `contains` the subject name:

```
if (_repository.Count <= 5 && (!_repository.Collection.Contains(SelectedSubjectName))) 
{
    _repository.Add(new ScoreModel() {Subject = SelectedSubjectName, Points = SelectedPoints});
    CalculateLeavingCertPoints();
}
```

But I get an overload mismatch error stating that:

> Error  1   The best overloaded method match for 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection<LC_Points.Model.ScoreModel>.Contains(LC_Points.Model.ScoreModel) has some invalid arguments

and

> Error  2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'LC_Points.Model.ScoreModel'

Does anyone have an idea how to fix the statement arguments?

I can see that the `SubjectName` is the string type, and that cannot be passed as an argument according to the second error. So I tried `ScoreModel.Subject` but that wasn't allowed by the compiler. Any advice appreciated.

This is the `ScoreModel` for reference:

http://hastebin.com/emagojojug.vala

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If _repository.Collection is a collection of ScoreModel objects, you cannot do a Contains with a string. You need to do the check with the specific property you want to avoid duplicates on.

So, replace this part:

```
!_repository.Collection.Contains(SelectedSubjectName)
```

by

```
_repository.Collection.All(s=>s.Subject != SelectedSubjectName)
```

This will be true if all existing subjects are different from the new subject name.
I believe this is what you are after.

Comment: I think `!_repository.Collection.Any(s=>s.Subject == SelectedSubjectName)` is better and more readable.

Comment: That's a matter of taste. In your syntax, the logic is split in 3 parts: the !, the Any and the ==, which to me it makes it more complex than 2 parts All and !=.

Comment: @FrancescCastells what does the s=> mean? It looks like its a temp variable that references the Subject field in the ScoreModel?

Comment: It's a lambda expression. In this case, the All method gives you a ScoreModel object and ask you to provide an expression with it with the condition you want to evaluate. This expression will be evaluated for all items in the collection and the All method will return true if all items evaluate to true. Read about lambda expressions anyway, it's a great knowledge to have.